# Should Countdown Clocks be extended when there are more players?

Tags: powered-by-the-apocalypse, the-sprawl, clocks

Countdown clocks are a nice mechanism for signalling urgency and for the MC to determine when things go bad, they have a limited number of steps available which will limit the number of times that players can screw up before the brown stuff hits the rotating object.

However in *The Sprawl* at least I can't find any suggestion or notes regarding handling when there are more/less players than the atypical group of four for a game - as if there are more players (8 in my case) then the countdown clocks will severely limit how much (if anything) some players can do before they need to deal with a problem or run for it.

Has there been any advice anywhere regarding modification of countdown clocks or changing how they're handled for larger number of players?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Discretion.

Aside from the Reporter, who's got their own personal clocks ticking, you're generally free to choose or not choose to advance a legwork, mission, or corporate clock as a result of a miss or choice given to you on a 7-9. Just make something else bad happen instead!

But in general, the larger number of people who can fail in your playgroup is going to be roughly balanced out by people having playbooks which have grounds to help each other out in almost every circumstance, and having more playbooks with a way to get free [intel] or [gear] on a mission.

Completely aside from the clock concern, though, eight people is kind of a lot to point any Powered by the Apocalypse game at, given how running it requires making a whole bunch of snap judgments and decisions about spotlight time live. (I've found my upper limit is six, though things suffer a bit even then.)

If you're sure you can handle it, more power to you, but I'd keep an eye on how you're doing there, even more than clocks.